# How to change a list attribute of an instance inside a list

Tags: python, list, class, attributes, instance

I have some trouble with the following code:

```
from beat_class import Beat

# creates a list 'beats' and fills it with instances of the class 'Beat'
beats = []
for i in range(4):
    beats.append(Beat())

# prints out the list attribute 'tones' of each 'Beat'-instance
for i in beats:
    print(i.tones)
print()

# appends an int value to the first instance of the list 'beats'
beats[0].tones.append(3)

# prints out the 'tones'-attributes again
for i in beats:
    print(i.tones)  
print()

# compares the ids of the first 2 instances in the list 'beats' and prints
# 'True' if they are the same
print(id(beats[0].tones) == id(beats[1].tones))
```

Output:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]

[3]
[3]
[3]
[3]

True
```

The comments in the code above show what its different parts do.

My problem is that once I want to append a value to the list attribute `tones` of an instance of the class `Beat` inside the list `beats`, said attribute gets changed in all of the instances instead of just the one I wanted to.

Since I‘m relatively new to Python I‘m not quite sure how to fix this. I assume that this has something to do with the ids of the `tones`-attributes which appear to be all the same according to the console output of the last line of code above.

I have already tried out some stuff with the `copy()` and `deepcopy()`functions but none of it worked. :/

I would be really happy if someone could help me out. :)

Comment: do you by chance have a list as a default argument to `__init__` or sth for `Beat`? can you show `Beat` class?

Comment: Your `Beat` class is presumably using a default `[]` value for `tones`.  This means it will return the *same* empty list for all new instances that don't specify a value for `tones`, rather than a new, unshared empty list for each new instance as you'd like.  It's a common mistake in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Does your `Beat`s `__init__` look something like:

```
class Beat:
   def __init__(self, tones=[]):
       self.tones = tones
```

If so, the problem is that tones defaults to the same list (actually the same list in memory). What you want is something like:

```
class Beat:
   def __init__(self, tones=None):
       self.tones = tones or []
```

That way you'll have a separate list for each `Beat` instance.

See more info on this [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)

Comment: @Truff2107 Please see [What to do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), this will help future readers and also allow to mark other questions as duplicates.